# getting comments in article with phantomjs

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am trying to extract the comments in this [website](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/inland/sterbehilfe-im-bundestag-unmoralisches-angebot-13887916.html).

[Inspection of element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUmaf.png)

I tried using urllib for this purpose but to no avail. Then I realized that since enabling javascript is necessary to do so, I used selenium and phantomjs to extract the comments as can be seen in the following python3 code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs')

url='http://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/inland/sterbehilfe-im-bundestag-unmoralisches-angebot-13887916.html'

driver.get(url)
htm_doc = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(htm_doc, 'html.parser')
print (soup.find('div', attrs={'id','lesermeinungen'}))
```

Since, the comments load while loading the page I simply access the source and try to see if there are any comments under the tag name 'lesermeinungen' as this is the section that appears when I insect the comments section.

However, it takes the result as `None`

**UPDATE**
Tried the following code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs')

url='http://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/inland/sterbehilfe-im-bundestag-unmoralisches-angebot-13887916.html'

driver.get(url)

wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver,3)

try:
    wait.until(driver.find_element_by_id('lesermeinungen'))
    htm_doc = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htm_doc, 'html.parser')
    print (soup.find('div', attrs={'id','lesermeinungen'}))

except TimeoutException:
    print ("Loading took too much time!")
```

No result even after 2 hours

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Vaviloff Hi, could you please check the edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo when searching for the element with beautifulsoup. Instead of

`print (soup.find('div', attrs={'id','lesermeinungen'}))`

it should be a colon, not a comma

`print (soup.find('div', attrs={'id' : 'lesermeinungen'}))`

With this correction your first example worked for me.

Comment: Silly me. Thank you very much

Comment: @Ekoji hey, was glad to help! If my answer was not only correct but also useful, you could upvote it to show that. Also: good question, really - there was enough of information to analyze and find solution.